# Odd postgres sequence behavior

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4, sequence

I have a table a Postgres 9.04 database with a table in it called Versions:

```
CREATE TABLE tracking."Versions"
(
    "ObjectId"      UUID            NOT NULL,
    "From"          BIGINT          NOT NULL,
    "To"            BIGINT,
    "DataTypeId"    INTEGER         NOT NULL REFERENCES tracking."DataTypes" ( "DataTypeId" ),
    CONSTRAINT "Versions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ObjectId", "DataTypeId")
);
```

There is also a sequence defined in the database that is used by the From & To columns:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tracking."dbVersion"
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
```

The Versions table is actually keeping track of changes made to other tables.  Without going into the details:

- When a row is created in one of these other tables, a row is added to the Versions table and the From column is supposed to be set to the next value of the sequence.
- If an existing row in one of those tables is updated, the From value of the corresponding row in the Versions table has to be set to the next value of the sequence.
- When a row in one of these other tables is deleted, the To column has to be set to the next value of the sequence.

Rather than setting the Default value of the From column to "nextval('tracking."dbVersion'), I implemented a stored function that returns the result of calling this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tracking."NextVersion"() RETURNS BIGINT
AS $$
    SELECT nextval('tracking."dbVersion"'::regclass);
$$ LANGUAGE Sql;
```

All my code for inserting rows into the tables is implemented in C# using Entity Framework 4.  All of the C# code is working fine.  The weird thing is that when I look at the data in the Versions table, the values in the From column are all even.  When I look at the sequence's properties in PgAdmin, it's odd.  But the next time a row is inserted, the value stored is even.

What am I doing wrong?  How does Postgres always use all of the values when you put that nextval call in the default property of a column?

Comment: 1. Why are you using this `tracking.NextVersion()` function, instead of calling nextval() directly? I don't see any advantage to using a function that only calls a function. 2. How are you assigning these values to your `From` column?

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework.  I don't know how to call the function directly from there.  Entity Framework can call stored functions very easily, so I wrapped the call in a stored functon so I could call it the only way I know how in C#.  The assignment is also done in C#:  version.From = context.NextVersion();

Comment: Without seeing your C# code it is probably impossible to know why you're only getting even numbers.  BUT... `nextval()` *is* a function, so if you can call `tracking.NextVersion()`, you should be able to call `nextval()` just as easily.

Comment: I wouldn't use C# to assign your `From` column value, though. Better to do that with a `DEFAULT` value, or a trigger (if it's needed for UPDATEs as well as INSERTs)

Comment: It's also needed to update the TO column on deletes.  Doing it in a trigger would make sense.  But I'd need to write a trigger for each table that we're tracking.  That's about a dozen or so triggers.  Not undoable.

Comment: I would still use it as a DEFAULT to handle the insert cases. Then write triggers to handle the UPDATE and DELETE cases, using the same sequence. That may be more code, as you say, but it will be far more efficient and more atomic than querying the DB for that value (especially if you're accessing the DB over a network, but even if you aren't). You may be able to use the same trigger function for multiple tables.

Comment: I just looked at my C# code.  It turns out I'm calling the NextVersion function 2x when adding a row.  That's where the problem is! <slapping self on forehead>

Comment: A dozen triggers is totally doable btw. It can be one trigger function in this case and a dozen (very simple) triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, time for me to feel sheepish.

I looked over my C# code for inserting rows into the Versions table & I found that I was actually calling the NextVersion stored procedure twice.  That explains why the sequence was always even when it was written to the From field.  I've removed the second call & problem solved.

Tony